# Use MediaWiki $wgLanguageCode in Extension

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

Is there a way to use/access `$wgLanguageCode` as defined in `LocalSettings.php` in an extension?

I'm using the `PageContentSaveComplete` hook, however, I can't seem to be able to find a method that returns the language (code).

Answer (score 1):

`$wgLanguageCode` is a global variable (though it's probably not the one you are looking for). It is available everywhere:

```
global $wgLanguageCode;
if ( $wgLanguageCode === 'ar'){
    echo('The default site language of this wiki is Arabic');
}
```

Other language settings you might want to check is the currently used language (probably more relevant in most cases): `$context->getLanguage()` – this will change according to user preferences, url parameters, and possibly extensions – and the content language for the current page: `$title->getPageLanguage()`.

For instance, if you access the [main page of Spanish Wikipedia in Danish](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Portada?uselang=da), the page language (`Title::getPageLanguage()`) will be `es`, because the content is in Spanish, while `RequestContext::getLanguage()` will be `da`, as that is the currently used language. The default language (`$wgLanguageCode`), of course, is still `es`.

You can also check the user's preferred language (for logged in users) like this: `$wgUser->getOption('language')`. That could in theory be something completely different, in this example.

edit: You don't mention if you are looking for the language front- och backend. In frontend, you have `wgPageContentLanguage`.

edit2: I'm leaving out language variants here. If your are on e.g. a Chinese wiki, things can be a bit more complex.